# -bash: java: command not found in Centos5

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, centos

```
# java -version
-bash: java: command not found
```

I have  `jdk1.8.0_40`  this folder in `usr/local`.
When I navigate to the folder and type `alternatives --config jar`, I get such output

```
There is 1 program that provides 'jar'.

      Selection    Command
    -----------------------------------------------
    *+ 1           /opt/jdk1.8.0_40//bin/jar

    Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

These are the content in jdk

```
bin    include     lib      README.html  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
COPYRIGHT  javafx-src.zip  LICENSE  release  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
db     jre         man      src.zip
```

Comment: Did you install it with `yum` or how?

Comment: @AndreKampling how can I install yum in jdk1.8.0_40 folder ?

Comment: I asked how did you install the jdk via `yum` or did you download the rpm or the sources and build it?

Comment: I think you are on the wrong site. I would try the `unix` stackexchange:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7160/installed-java-but-java-version-not-showing-new-java

Comment: I think you installed it the wrong way and because of that the path is not set right.

Comment: You configured alternatives for `jar` but what about `java`?

Comment: @AndreKampling I'm not the one that downliad the jdk folder. So I not sure about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install java first:

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java <path to java>
```

Change the  var in above command to appropriate location of you java file, for example: `/usr/local/jdk/bin/java`

And then run the following command to set it as default java:

```
alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your installation path to your PATH variable. Bash only looks for executables in the paths defined by your PATH variable.